# Which regression coefficient should be used to calculate Odds ratio? Standardized or unstandardized?

Tags: logistic, regression-coefficients, multilevel-analysis, odds-ratio

I've run a multilevel logistic regression in R, and I want to calculate the Odds Ratios for the predictors in the model.

R automatically gives the unstandardized regression coefficients for a multilevel log regression, do I need to first standardize the predictors before calculating Odds ratio?

In simple words: is Odds ratio the exponentiated beta(standardized) coefficient, or is it the exponentiated unstandardized coefficient? I've seen people use both so I am confused as to what's the right way.

Comment: There are ways to do this based on running your model (see https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/mplus/faq/how-does-mplus-calculate-the-standardized-coefficients-based-on-a-logistic-regression/) but you can also standardize predictors beforehand and run the GLMM on those. The results should be very similar but you should probably look into it a bit more. See also the `standardize_parameters` function in the `parameters` package (https://easystats.github.io/parameters/articles/standardize_parameters_effsize.html).

Comment: Hi Erik, thank you, yes I know how to standardize the predictors.. my question is more conceptual than practical

Comment: Understood. Personally, when running logistic models, I prefer to work with marginal effects to avoid this whole confusion. Marginal effects are re-expressions of the coefficient in terms of the average change in the probability of the outcome happening for a 1-unit change in the predictor. The `marginaleffects` and `ggeffects` packages in R are great for this.